# Reproducing the cox model score test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, cox-model, logrank-test

I am using R and would like to recreate by hand the values of the tests.

For example,

```
data(rats)
test=coxph(Surv(time,tumor)~trt,data=rats)
summary(test)

      coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   
trt 0.9047    2.4711   0.3175 2.849  0.00438 **

Likelihood ratio test= 7.97  on 1 df,   p=0.004744
Wald test            = 8.12  on 1 df,   p=0.004382
Score (logrank) test = 8.68  on 1 df,   p=0.003219
```

I can recreate the LRT by doing

```
> -2*(test$loglik[1]-test$loglik[2])
[1] 7.97455
```

And the wald test by

```
> (0.9047 -0)^2/ 0.3175^2
[1] 8.119359
```

And I know that the score test can be found by doing

```
> test$score
[1] 8.678791
```

But how is that number calculated from the numbers we have?

Comment: In the R `Hmisc` package see the `logrank` function.  The log-rank statistic is the Cox score statistic especially when no ties occur in survival times.

Comment: I rant it with the rats data, and we get something close.

logrank(Surv(rats\$ time,rats\$tumor),rats\$trt)
[1] 8.59446
attr(,"hr")
[1] 2.114888

Is this difference due to ties in survival times?

Comment: Yes probably so.